# bootstrap push pull trouble

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble using bootstraps pull and pull features 
I have want to have my site looking like this for

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBGN3.png)

And like this for

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JmyO.png)

I understand I have to use push and pull somehow but I cant figure out how, any help would be appreciated.

edit:

I should say what is currently happing is on mobile the stack goes 
image-text-text-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### As you can see, you want:

```
T1 M1   (Desktop)
M2 T2


T1      (mobile)
M1
T2
M2
```

#### For `T1 M1 -> T1 M1` just use normal `col`,

#### For `M2 T2 -> T2 M2` you need use `push/pull` to reverse the order

check the example here for `push/pull`: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex9&stacked=h

#### combine those two:

```css
.textbox {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container content">
  <div class="row">

    <!--text 1-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="textbox">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000/fff" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--img 1-->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="textbox">
        text 1
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--img 2-->
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3">
      <div class="textbox">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000/fff" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--text 2-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9">
      <div class="textbox">
        text 2
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to use bootstrap's css query classes. This [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) can help in understanding how to transition from mobile to desktop.